# Mac OS 10.6.8 Firewall Blocking Wiki for ONE User

Tags: firewall, unix, mac, wiki

This is a very bizarre issue that I hope someone can help with. We're running 10.6.8 server to host our internal wiki. We had the firewall enabled on that machine without any issues. Last week one user wasn't able to get onto the wiki. In troubleshooting their workstation I found they couldn't access the wiki via Safari under any user account (including a fresh test account). They *could* access it through another browser (Chrome + FF). They could also access sharepoints on that server. I deleted some Safari system-wide prefs to no avail.

For kicks, I disabled the firewall on the server and they could access the wiki via Safari. So, I assumed it was the adaptive firewall. I checked the AF blacklist file but her machine wasn't on it. In spite of that I whitelisted the user's machine, no change. I disabled the adaptive firewall altogether, no change. I enabled logging for denied packets and watched when her machine connected. Four ports were blocked, 4097,2052,17500,5353. I've temporarily created a FW rule to allow those ports, no change. I then tried keeping the firewall on but allowing all connections and she still couldn't access the wiki from Safari on her machine.

I'm stumped. It seems like it should be the adaptive firewall but that makes no sense when there's nothing in the blacklist file and the AF is disabled. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I realize she can use Chrome or FF as a workaround for now but it should be a resolvable issue.